# Parent Case Custom Buttom to mirror some fields

Tags: custom-button, service-cloud-console, urlhacking, case-object, custom-url

I want to create a Custom List Button on the Case Object on the Service Console that creates a new case link via the Parent case and mirrors some fields from the original case.

This is what I got:

```
/lightning/o/Case/new?count=1&nooverride=1&useRecordTypeCheck=1&navigationLocation=RELATED_LIST&recordTypeId=012740000004PxGAAU&ParentId={!Case.Id}&Reason={!Case.Reason}&Case_Reason_II__c={!Case.Case_Reason_II__c}&OwnerId={!Case.OwnerId}&Landlord_Owner_Account__c={!Case.Landlord_Owner_Account__c}&AssetId={!Case.Asset}
```

When I test it, I only get the Record Type, the rest of the url gets flushed. Any idea?

After:

```
lightning/o/Case/new?count=1&nooverride=1&useRecordTypeCheck=1&navigationLocation=RELATED_LIST&recordTypeId=012740000004PxGAAU
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this format:-

```
/lightning/o/Case/new?&defaultFieldValues=ParentId={!Case.Id},Reason={!Case.Reason}
```

If you have to add recordtypeid as well, you can do like this:-

```
/lightning/o/Case/new?&recordTypeId=012740000004PxGAAU&defaultFieldValues=ParentId={!Case.Id},Reason={!Case.Reason}
```

I trie this and it worked fine:-

[image]

[image]